# Android создание AsynkTask в соседнем классе и передача результата в активити

Tags: android, activity, android-asynctask

В соседнеем классе создаю AsynkTask и результат хочу вывести в активити. Как можно передать результат? Логи сейчач говорят, что передаю null. Реализацию с inner class сделать я могу, но вот хочу разобраться в этом.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyTask myTask;

    TextView tvTask1, tvTask2, tvTask3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvTask1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTask1);
        tvTask2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTask2);
        tvTask3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTask3);
    }

    public void onClickStart(View view) {
        myTask = new MyTask();
        myTask.execute();
    }
}


public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

    MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();

    private static final String LOG = "myLogs";

    int i;

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            publishProgress(i);
        }
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        Log.d(LOG, "" + values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
        Log.d(LOG, "Result = " + integer);
        activity.tvTask2.setText(Integer.valueOf(integer));
    }
}
```

Comment: Первым делом вам надо передать в AsyncTask экземпляр той активити, которая отображается на экране, а не создавать новый экземпляр в AsyncTask и пытаться установить туда какой то результат.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy: [Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12575319/5330439) (*Перевод свободный, частичный*)

1. Создайте класс `interface`, где`String output` является необязательным или может быть любой переменной, которую вы хотите вернуть.

   ```
   public interface AsyncResponse {
       void processFinish(String output);
   }
   ```
2. Перейдите в `AsyncTask` class, и задекларируйте поле с переменной  `AsyncResponse`:

   ```
   public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{
     public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         delegate.processFinish(result);
       }
    }
   ```
3. В вашем  MainActivity вам нужно реализовать (`implements`) interface `AsyncResponse`.

   ```
   public class MainActivity implements AsyncResponse{
     MyAsyncTask asyncTask =new MyAsyncTask();

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //this to set delegate/listener back to this class
        asyncTask.delegate = this;

        //execute the async task 
        asyncTask.execute();
     }

     //this override the implemented method from asyncTask
     @Override
     void processFinish(String output){
        //Here you will receive the result fired from async class 
        //of onPostExecute(result) method.
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: Как я писал выше, что иннер класс я могу сделать и он будет работать,  а вот хотелось бы научиться делать как я описал.

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос, то можно попробовать использовать механизм Handler`ов и sendMessage у нужного хендлера.

Вот [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/145-urok-82-handler-primer-s-bolee-soderzhatelnymi-soobschenijami.html) можно посмотреть, как это использовать, грамотно написанный урок

Comment: В сети много примеров,  это все знают. Привидите Ваш.

Comment: вот [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/145-urok-82-handler-primer-s-bolee-soderzhatelnymi-soobschenijami.html) можно посмотреть, как это использовать, грамотно написанный урок