# Как из BackgroundWorker вернуть значение?

Tags: android

В общем, есть окно (activity) в котором я хочу получить значение из `public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>` (класс для выполнения фоновой работы).

В activity происходит следующее:

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
String type = "test";
String test1 = "test1";
String test2 ="";
backgroundWorker.execute(type, test1);
```

А в BackgroundWorker в `protected String doInBackground(String...params)` я получаю `String result`
И как мне вернуть `result` чтобы `test2` приравнять к нему?

Comment: можно использовать коллбек https://stackoverflow.com/a/47161767/13840814

Answer (score 2):

Вообще - никак. Можно ужасным костылём, который ваше приложение сломает. Например так:

`String test2 = backgroundWorker.execute(type, test1).get();`

Но ни в коем случае так не делайте, т.к. это заморозит главный поток и приложение однажды выдаст ANR.

Вам надо просто учесть, что результат вызова не факт что придёт и неизвестно когда это вообще случится. Соответственно, вам надо создать метод, который может быть вызван если, вдруг, всё получится и результат выполнения задачи будет успешным. Этот метод объявите в интерфейсе, реализуйте его в активити и передайте активити в виде интерфейса через конструктор задачи. В onPostExecute вызовите метод переданного интерфейса. Так вызовется метод активити, в который вы сможете передать данные, полученные в задаче.

Comment: Я пытался воспользоваться таким костылем, но это даже не начинало работать на стадии сборки.
"передайте активити в виде интерфейса через конструктор задачи" - не очень понимаю что значит данная фраза, я передаю интерфейс в параметрах backgroundWorker.execute? И вот у меня есть интерфейс с объявленным методом, реализация метода происходит в активити, а что должно происходить в реализации этого метода, просто каким образом возвращается значение после вывоза метода в onPostExecute?

Comment: Вот тут есть пример с интерфейсом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/677054/17609

Comment: Вот если бы это решение работало, если я следую тому примеру, то во время выполнения onPostExecute у меня происходит то ли ошибка, то ли выброс исключения, метод вызывается и данные передаются, но между этим и попыткой воспользоваться этими данными(ну хоть вывести их), что-то ломается, и это видно только при отладке, а само приложение работает. Будто данные теряются или сбрасываются, не понимаю в чем дело

Comment: Вы что-то очень странное описываете. Если что-то падает - то должен быть лог. Если он есть - покажите его. Если его нет... То почти ничем помочь нельзя - только если посоветовать переписать заново на другом подходе, т.к. из вашего описания проблемы не понять в чём она заключается.

Comment: Так, щас попробую задать вопрос-уточнение, в том примере в activity есть строка  asyncTask.delegate = this; что она делает? Пояснение в комментарии не очень помогает и когда я смотрю по отладке на asyncTask.execute(); у меня вообще ничего не происходит, то есть фоновый процесс не выполняется и как в следствии Onpostexecute не работает и метод не вызывается и данных у меня нет.

Comment: `asyncTask.delegate = this;` Это передача класса, реализующего интерфейс в класс, который будет вызывать метод интерфейса. Попробуйте без отладки код запустить, выводя в логи что-то. Может быть вы точку остановки сделали - вот оно дальше и не идёт? Либо вы пытаетесь повторно `execute()` вызвать, что, вроде, нельзя.